# in a Flask unit-test, how can I mock objects on the request-global `g` object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, flask, werkzeug

I have a flask application that is setting up a database connection in a `before_filter`, very similar to [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/dbcon/):

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()
```

Now: I am writing some unit-tests and I do *not* want them to hit the database. I want to replace `g.db` with a mock object that I can set expectations on.

My tests are using `app.test_client()`, as is demonstrated in the flask documentation [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/). An example test looks something like

```
def test(self):
    response = app.test_client().post('/endpoint', data={..})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    ...
```

The tests work and pass, but they are hitting the database and as I said I want to replace db access with mock objects. I do not see any way in `test_client` to access the `g` object or alter the before_filters.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This works

`test_app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, g

app = Flask(__name__)

def connect_db():
    print 'I ended up inside the actual function'
    return object()

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()


@app.route('/')
def root():
    return 'Hello, World'
```

`test.py`

```
from mock import patch
import unittest

from test_app import app


def not_a_db_hit():
    print 'I did not hit the db'

class FlaskTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('test_app.connect_db')
    def test_root(self, mock_connect_db):
        mock_connect_db.side_effect = not_a_db_hit
        response = app.test_client().get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

So this will print out 'I did not hit the db', rather than 'I ended up inside the actual function'. Obviously you'll need to adapt the mocks to your actual use case.

Comment: Trying this (I had to change it to 'flask_module.g.connect_db') gives a `RuntimeError: working outside of request context`

Comment: I just wrote up a more full example which I've actually tested and have working.

Comment: I like the idea! The only part I don't understand is `g = G()`, why is that necessary?

Comment: It's not, I just needed an object with an attribute `db` to make the tests work. Presumably you already have one of those :-)

Comment: @GabeMoothart The ``g`` object is specific to Flask and resets its attributes after each request. I don't think it'd be a good idea to just use an arbitrary object for it which doesn't behave like that.

Comment: I think you are simply misunderstanding the example. When I post answers I like to have actually run them. The global 'g' object is irrelevant because it is not being patched. Instead the function being patched is `connect_db`. You might want to have a play with the mock and patch libraries before randomly downvoting accepted answers.

Comment: Looking back onto this i can't see how i managed to misunderstand this. Unfortunately my vote is being locked by now. Sorry.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for having another look at it anyway.

Comment: @aychedee I agree with @markus-unterwaditzer. But it is very simple to clarify your answer: Simply remove your custom `G` object and add `g` to your Flask imports. So you should have `from flask import Flask, g`. It will make the answer much clearer!

Comment: I guess so, we'll see if it does.

Comment: have any idea about how test_client bypasses the before_request process?

Comment: It doesn't... the before_request call is still being made. But the code that it runs has been patched.