# Mock flask.g in the post request unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-unittest

Here is `test.py`, where using `mock_service` I am mocking the cursor and db, But Everytime I am getting `'function' object has no attribute 'cursor'`. How to properly mock the flask.g object. I referred this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131494/in-a-flask-unit-test-how-can-i-mock-objects-on-the-request-global-g-object)

```
test.py
def not_a_db_hit():
     print('I did not hit the DB')
     return object()

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

@mock.patch('utils.configure_db') #configure_db returns database
@mock.patch('Service.g')
def test_insert_cricket_data(self, mock_service, mock_db):
    with app.app_context():
        body = {
            'key1': 'value1'
        }
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }

        mock_db.return_value = not_a_db_hit
        mock_service.cursor.return_value = not_a_db_hit
        mock_service.cursor.execute.return_value = None
        mock_service.db.commit.return_value = None
        response = self.app.post('/insertvalue', headers=headers.items(), data=json.dumps(body))
        print(response)
```

Here is My `Service.py`  File

```
from flask import g 

@service.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = configure_db()
    g.cursor = g.db.cursor()

@service.route('/insertvalue', methods=['POST'])
def in_request():
    ....
    try:
        g.cursor.execute(sql, main_values)
        g.db.commit()
        return make_response("Created", 201)
```

Any Help, Appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'd say that you're not using g properly for this use case. You should take a look at flaskr: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/database/. And then, see how they do here: https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/tutorial
They create a test database that they use for their test. Then they don't need to mock the cursor. If you really need to mock the cursor, then keep how they're doing. Because you must import your db module as they do, then you can easily mock a function from this module, easier than g.

Comment: Its Helpful!! Thanks